# Mongodb $lookup with condition

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb version 4.4.3 and I want to fetch all allerts which has tmeplates relation and which templates has deviceStatus relation

Alert document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6034f08a025fd735035d26c4"),
    "templates" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "Template",
            "$id" : ObjectId("6034f050bba852116468c993")
        }
    ]
}
```

and Templat document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6034f050bba852116468c993"),
    "deviceStatus" : {
        "value" : "hold"
    },
}
```

since like that [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#unwind-example) my query should return me object alert where should be full object Template

```
db.getCollection('Alert').aggregate([  
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'Template',
            localField: 'templates',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'templateObject'
        }
    }
])
```

but I had empty `templateObject`
Or this happened becuase I have templates array objects which contains two column $ref and $id instead exactly $id for correct lookup ? How to buid this query ritgh ?

When I changed structure to

```
"templates" : [ 
        ObjectId("6041e12c2845427b5f2ff7d3")
    ],
```

instead fo

```
"templates" : [ 
    {
        "$ref" : "Template",
        "$id" : ObjectId("6034f050bba852116468c993")
    }
]
```

everything works correct

My question how to reproduce the same way when I have this struture ?

```
    "templates" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "Template",
            "$id" : ObjectId("6034f050bba852116468c993")
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
db.getCollection('Alert').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'Template',
            let: { "template_id": "$templates.$id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$template_id"] }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: 'templateObject'
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: toy are absolutely ritgh

Answer (score 0):

Just use `'templates.$id'` in `localField`:

```
db.getCollection('Alert').aggregate([  
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'Template',
            localField: 'templates.$id',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'templateObject'
        }
    }
])
```